# Eval LaTeX code in R chunk (Knitr)

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm actually creating a shiny app. In that app, there is a download button which download a PDF file that depends of user's input.

So I use a `.rnw` file to do generate that PDF document. I just want to do a table (with tabular) which have a number of row that depends of app user's input.

So in my R chunck, i'd like to do something like that :

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
for (index in 1:nrow(myData))
{
   SomethingThatRunLaTeXCode(paste0("\hline ",
  "\Sexpr{",myData[index,1],"}"," % ","\Sexpr{",myData[index,2],"}"))
}
\hline
\end{tabular}
@
```

Comment: Why not use `kable` or `xtable` to make the table instead?

Comment: I try it and I tell you. Thx !

Comment: xtable generate a latex code that is print on my PDF but I don't have a table on it... 
I'm doing : 
`<<echo=FALSE,results="tex">>=

  data_tab <- data_init[-1,];

  df <- data.frame("Vos commentaires :" = 
data_tab[intersect(intersect(all_v,which(!is.na(data_init[,28]))),which(str_replace_all(data_tab[,28]," ","")!="")),28]);

  xtab<-xtable(df);

  print.xtable(df);

  @`

Comment: @Smich7 I do not have a TeX typesetting system installed on the computer I am currently on but I would expect your comment code to work if you do `<<echo = FALSE, results = "asis">>= xtable(df) @` with `df` defined as in your comment (and with appropriate linebreaks).

Comment: My previous comment was a little fast: it works if you use Knitr instead of Sweave (which I find far superior).

Comment: Yes thanks that works fine. I used Knitr !
Another question if you can answer me :
How can I have an automatic page break in that generated xtable ?Because I have got 2 columns in it and the second contains very long string charecters. And the text continue line by line to the right side of the document before that they are ended

Comment: @Therkel, you should make an answer. Smich7, I recommend making another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by sebastian-c, a much better way to make such a table is to use the `xtable` package together with Knitr. To make the Knitr chunks understand TeX, use the chunk option `results='asis'`.

Since your data is a `data.frame`, it is straight-forward:

```
<<echo = FALSE, results = "asis">>= 

## test data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Gaussian = rnorm(10), Exponential = rexp(10))

library(xtable)
cap = paste("My caption can span multiple lines and",
            "can be arbitrarily long.")
xtable(df,caption = cap)
@
```

For full customization, use the function `print.xtable` on your `xtable` object.

```
<<echo = FALSE, results = "asis">>=
print.xtable(xtable(df),table.placement = "")
@
```